# $\Omega(f) = \mathbb{S}^1$ $ \Leftrightarrow$ for all $I \in \mathbb{S}^1$ open, we have that $\bigcup_{k \geq 1}f^{k}(I)$ is dense on $\mathbb{S}^1$

Tags: analysis, algebraic-topology, dynamical-systems, covering-spaces

Let $f : \mathbb{S}^1 \longrightarrow \mathbb{S}^1 $ be a $n$-sheet covering, with $n \geq 2$. Define $\Omega(f)$ as the set of points $x \in \mathbb{S}^1$ such that for any neighborhood $I$ of $x$ on $\mathbb{S}^1$, there exists an integer $k \geq 1$ such thar $f^{k}(I) \cap I \neq \emptyset$.

Show that $\Omega(f) = \mathbb{S}^1$ if and only if, for all open $I \in \mathbb{S}^1$, we have that $\bigcup_{k \geq 1}f^{k}(I)$ is dense on $\mathbb{S}^1$.

My attempt to show that $\bigcup_{k \geq 1}f^{k}(I)$ is dense on $\mathbb{S}^1$ is taking a point $x \in \overline{\bigcup_{k \geq 1}f^{k}(I)} $, so i have a sequence ${x_n} \longrightarrow x$, with ${x_n}$ on $f^{k}(I)$ for some k. After that i couldn't finish how $\overline{\bigcup_{k \geq 1}f^{k}(I)} \subset  \mathbb{S}^1 $.

Comment: @PaulFrost, i think if $ I = \mathbb{S}^{1} $, then $ f(I) = \mathbb{S}^{1} $ where $ k=1 $, because $ f $ is a covering. Thus $ \overline{\mathbb{S}^{1}} = \mathbb{S}^{1} $.

Comment: I believe the "for any" should be interpreted as "for every", not "there exists".

Comment: I suggest trying to prove the contrapositive here; if there is an open $U$ and $y$ with $y \notin \bigcup_k f^k(U)$, then there is some open $I \ne \varnothing$ for which $f^k(I) \cap I = \varnothing$ for all $k$.